# Can't read Google Storage Cloud file in upload success handler

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get file content from 'upload success' handler in GAE. File is uploaded to the url:

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/onupload", uploadOptions));
```

So, in `/onupload`, I'm doing like:

```
BlobKey myFile = context.getRequestBlobs().get("myFile").get(0);
```

and then I've tried:

```
InputStream is = new BlobstoreInputStream(myFile);
// .. read the stream
```

which failed with `com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreInputStream$BlobstoreIOException: BlobstoreInputStream received an invalid blob key: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?AMIfv96J=2DsyIbhm5=5FET?=`

and

```
FileReadChannel ch = fileService.openReadChannel(myFile, false);
```

which failed with

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:615)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:588)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.open(FileServiceImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.openForRead(FileServiceImpl.java:481)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.openForRead(FileServiceImpl.java:473)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.openReadChannel(FileServiceImpl.java:197)
```

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong and is it possible at all to read file's content in upload hander?

Note, that for blobstore fs (not GS) it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to read a file from the google cloud storage.
Have you seen the example [1] on the docs?

Particularly this part:

```
/ At this point, the file is visible in App Engine as:
// "/gs/BUCKETNAME/FILENAME"
// and to anybody on the Internet through Cloud Storage as:
// (http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKETNAME/FILENAME)
// We can now read the file through the API:
String filename = "/gs/" + BUCKETNAME + "/" + FILENAME;
AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile(filename);
FileReadChannel readChannel =
    fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile, false);
// Again, different standard Java ways of reading from the channel.
BufferedReader reader =
         new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
String line = reader.readLine();
resp.getWriter().println("READ:" + line);

// line = "The woods are lovely, dark, and deep."
readChannel.close();
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview#Complete_Sample_App

Comment: well, good thing, but I don't have file name due to a bug in GS/GAE (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8337) and having blob key (as shown in the question) I can't create read channel...

Comment: If you want to upload a file, don't use the Blobstore service. You can use [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms) and write directly to the GS (without Blobstore).

Comment: Why does this not work for large blobs? You can write the uploaded bytes directly to the GS. Or is there a limitation in the GAE?

Comment: There is a limitation on query execution time. So if I not use .createUploadUrl() API but just do PUT request to GS, GAE shuts me down...

Comment: I think you are using this API https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview . I don't know if there is a timeout, but if you get one, you maybe can split the files into parts. Close the file after every part and closeFinally after the whole file was uploaded. After closing the file use e new GS request to continue the file upload to the GS.